# Are the following two random variables independent?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Consider two bounded domains $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ and a bounded smooth function $g : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $W_t$ is Brownian motion started in $x \in U \cap V$ and $\tau_A$ is the first exit time from a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

Are the random variables $X(\omega)=\textbf{1}_{\{\tau_U < \tau_V\}}(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)=E[\int_{0}^{\tau_V}g(W_s+W_{\tau_U}(\omega))ds]$ independent? I want to split the expectation of the product of both, so it would also be enough if they were just uncorrelated.

Intuitively I would say no but I am not able to justify my intuition.

Comment: Maybe you should establish with respect to which $\sigma$-algebra each of those random variables are measurable.

Comment: @TheBridge I have tried this. Clearly the smallest $\sigma$-algebra, $\textbf{1}_{\{\tau_U < \tau_V\}}(\omega)$ is measurable is $\{\emptyset, \{\tau_U < \tau_V \}, \{\tau_U \geq \tau_V \} , \Omega\}$. To establish it for the other random variable, is beyond my intuition...Can you help?

Comment: No even the $\sigma$-algebra for the first random variable is wrong as it depends on $\omega$...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notation you're using. Is $Y$ defined by a conditional expectation? I'm reading it as a conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma(W_{\tau_U})$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow I have rewritten it. Maybe it is clearer now? It just means that the Brownian motion in the integrand $W_s$ starts at some point $x_0(\omega)=W_{\tau_U}(\omega)$ where an (other) Brownian motion (started at $x \in U \cap V$) has hit $U$.

Comment: @nabla Thanks for the clarification. Just making sure of one more thing, is the Brownian motion started at $x=W_{\tau_U}(\omega)$ assumed to have increments independent of the Brownian motion up to time $\tau_U$ used to generate $W_{\tau_U}(\omega)$? Also would this still be well-defined if $W_{\tau_U}(\omega) \notin V$?

Comment: @forgottenarrow Good point! Yes the Brownian motion started at $x = W_{\tau_U}(\omega)$ is just a completely "new" Brownian motion independent from its past (I have used the strong Markov property before). If $W_{\tau_U}(\omega) \notin V$ the integral is just supposed to be 0. This should be fine I guess.

Comment: Then don't we already have dependence? Let $g\equiv 1$ be constant. Then if $X = 1$, $Y > 0$ almost surely. However, if $X=0$, then (assuming $U$ is not a subset of $V$) there is a positive probability that $W_{\tau_U}(\omega) \notin V$, so $Y=0$ with positive probability. However, I suspect this is not the kind of dependence you were thinking of when you proposed the problem?

Comment: You are right. I get your example and may have thought it too complicated. However let me rethink this some hours and come back again. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I hope this helped!

Comment: @forgottenarrow Ok this indeed what I needed. Have thought it too complicated. Thanks a lot! Please post your comment with the example as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming we are working with the definitions,

$$X(\omega) = \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau_U < \tau_V\}}(\omega) \text{ and } Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\tau_U}^{\max\{\tau_U,\tau_V\}} g(W_s(\omega))\,ds\middle|W_{\tau_U}(\omega)\right].$$

Suppose $g$ is a strictly positive function bounded from below by some $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose $U$ and $V$ are closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a non-trivial intersection, and $U$ is not a subset of $V$. Then if $X = 0$, $\tau_V \leq \tau_U$, so $\max\{\tau_U,\tau_V\} = \tau_U$. Then,

$$Y = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\tau_U}^{\tau_U} g(W_s(\omega))\,ds\middle|W_{\tau_U}(\omega)\right] = 0.$$

However, if $X = 1$, then $\tau_V > \tau_U$. Thus, $\mathbb{E}[\tau_V - \tau_U] > 0$. Then,

$$Y = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\tau_U}^{\tau_V} g(W_s(\omega))\,ds\middle|W_{\tau_U}(\omega)\right] \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon (\tau_V - \tau_U)\middle|W_{\tau_U}(\omega)\right] > 0.$$

Thus,

$$0 = \mathbb{P}\left(Y > 0 \middle| X = 0\right) \neq \mathbb{P}\left(Y > 0\middle| X = 1\right) > 0.$$

We conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Based on what you said in the comments I tried to redefine $Y$. Did I get it right?